# What is the proper way to format a CGFloat in Swift?

Tags: swift, formatting

WWDC 2021 introduced a new formatter API. ([WWDC video, 14:35](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10109/)) It can be used with numbers, dates, date ranges, and other core types.

```swift
let n: Double = ...
n.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
```

But this doesn't work on a `CGFloat`, even though the `formatted` function is defined on `BinaryFloatingPoint` protocol, to which `CGFloat` conforms.

Is there nice way to define `.number` for CGFloat, so you can treat it exactly like `Double`?

```swift
let n: CGFloat = ....
n.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))
```

This is my guess. Is it correct? I can't see the definitions for `Double` and `Float`.

```swift
extension FormatStyle where Self == FloatingPointFormatStyle<CGFloat> {
    public static var number: FloatingPointFormatStyle<CGFloat> {
        return .init(locale: Locale.current)
    }
}
```

Comment: The code seems to work fine so what is the question?

Comment: It seems odd to me that I have to define that thing myself. There is no documentation saying to do it, and the `.formatted(...)` method is defined in `BinaryFloatingPoint`, so you'd think it would just work for all `BinaryFloatingPoint`, including `CGFloat`.

Comment: Ok but there is no FormatStyle.number defined for BinaryFloatingPoint (or CGFloat) which is what you pass to the `formatted()` function

Comment: @RobN Seems correct. Note that there is no need to pass the locale to the method as it has already a default value of `.autoupdatingCurrent`. So you can simply do `public static var number: Self { .init() }`